# Outlook using rules not showing new message alert in system tray

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

I created a few rules for Microsoft Outlook 2010, that specific mails go to specific folders. This works fine, but I don't get an alert in system tray when I have new mails.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the sources I've listed below, this seems to not be possible, and it seems to be expected behavior of MS Office since 2007.

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/show-an-envelope-icon-in-the-taskbar-and-play-a/7c5608af-dca4-46c7-ad40-bd959a2c1402
- http://www.msofficeforums.com/outlook/6140-modifying-rule-show-new-mail-envelope-task.html
- http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/missingenvelope.htm

I would love for someone to prove me wrong, because I would like to have an envelope as well.  Wish MS would at least give an option to turn this setting on and off.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with an additional rule.

1. Open the Rules and Alerts dialog;

   - Outlook 2003 an Outlook 2007: Tools-> Rules and Alerts… (press OK if you get an HTTP warning)
   - Outlook 2010: tab Home->  group Move-> button Rules-> Manage Rules & Alerts…
   - Outlook 2013: File/Home -> Manage Rules and Alerts
2. Button New Rule…
3. Select "Start from a blank rule" and verify that "Check messages when they arrive" is selected.
4. Press Next to go to the Conditions screen.
5. Verify that no condition is selected and press Next.
6. A warning will pop-up stating that this rule will apply to all messages. Press "Yes" to indicate that that is correct.
7. Select the action "display a Desktop Alert".
8. Press Finish to complete the rule.
9. If needed move the "display a Desktop Alert" rule all the way to the top.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/df4b0309-beb0-4eb8-9e90-e06214e5c1bf/notifications-envelope-not-showing-for-subfolders-using-rule-move-to-folder?forum=outlook

I just added the Outlook 2013 part, because this old question/problem is still relevant in the current version where I use this mechanism successfully.

Comment: This shows a desktop alert alright, but does not display the envelop icon in the systray as asked.